# How to exclude a particular file with GNUMake's wildcard function?

Tags: unix, grep, gnu-make

My project's directory structure is as follows:

[image]

My Makefile looks like this:

```
dir1_contents := $(wildcard dir1/*) 
dir3_contents := $(wildcard dir3/*)

all: clean_dir1 clean_dir3

clean_dir1:
    echo 'dir1_contents = $(dir1_contents)'

clean_dir3:
echo 'dir3_contents = $(dir3_contents)'
```

When I run make, this is what I get:

```
$ pwd
make-test

$ make -s
dir1_contents = dir1/dir2 dir1/file2.junk dir1/file3.junk
dir3_contents = dir3/file4.junk
```

I want to get the contents of `dir1` in `dir1_contents`. But I want to exclude `file3.junk` from that list. How can I do it?

Perhaps I should use `grep -v`? But I'm not sure that's the best way. Is there a built-in GNUMake function I can use here?

Answer (score 3):

Use the `$(filter-out` *pattern*, *text* `)` [text function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)

```
 $(filter-out file3.junk,${dir1_contents})
```

<sup>(someone suggested to use `%/file3.junk` instead of `file3.junk`, but I believe you don't need that; I leave you to experiment)</sup>

Comment: I don't think the correction (with `%/`) is correct.